# CTRL-Z hang from Emacs using Xming and VcXsrv

Tags: c, emacs, freebsd

I know what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does. I should be also capable of not hitting it, but I do hit it accidentally and I would like it to work properly.

In Emacs, under Xwindows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> minimizes the frame.  It's handy.  However... when I'm on windows using emacs over the network and using either Xming or VcXsrv the particular window in which I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will never work again.

That's right ... if I have several windows open, other windows are fine. In fact, if I hit the close window decoration, I get a popup window to save my file --- which works fine.

But ... when I bring back up the window in which I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, I cannot move the cursor with a click, type anything.  Even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

So... How do I fix this?

(full environment for the curious:

- win10 w/ Xming or VcXsrv
- putty/sshd with X11 forwarding
- FreeBSD 10 or 11 with emacs24

Comment: On Windows Ctrl+Z sets the end-of-file condition for the terminal window. Like Ctrl+D on Linux.

Comment: I also work remotely and had clashes between windows and linux\ emacs hotkeys. There's no nice answer for this - try changing the windows binding of Ctrl-Z or at least make sure the hotkeys you use for emacs\ linux are not clashing with state-shifting hotkeys of windows, which will prevail.

Comment: I don't think this is a "hotkey" missmatch.  CTRL-Z works in many editors as undo and it works in putty just fine.  Only in an XWindows emacs does it freeze the window (and only that one window ... not other windows of the same emacs process).  Heck... it works properly in the emacs compiled for windows, too... so hotkey conflict sounds like a stretch.

Comment: None of that terminal stuff is relevant: this is an X window, not a TTY.

Comment: Just as an update.  emacs-27 running from FreeBSD 11 to 13 onto the current VcXsrv seems to have gotten past this bug.  No idea what the new WSL X emulation will do tho :)

Answer (score 2):

When running graphical emacs (using 25.1) from WSL Ubuntu connected to VcXsrv, I hit Ctrl-Z once in a while accidentally, because of muscle memory for "undoing". I experience similar freezes.

*When this happens, as a workaround, try maximizing the window, and resetting the size to normal.*

In my case, Ctrl-Z will minimize the app, but also partially freeze the GUI: the main buffer window doesn't seem to refresh, my mark/cursor disappears, I can't seem to be able to type new text, and the scrollbar won't respond. However, the emacs `File`, `Edit`, etc. toolbar options still seem to remain alive and respond to clicks.

I can get my window revived by maximizing the window, and resizing it normally. My cursor and visuals come back to normal after that.

Comment: And what about when you run emacs on fullscreen mode (F11) ? How do you maximizing the window ?